# Tekken 7 website html hidden line of code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been referencing various professional website's html code as I try to write my own (I'm new to html, css, javascript etc.) and I noticed that if I view the site's code through the inspect element feature (ctrl+shift+c) they have the main body inside divs with id's and classes like wrapper, contents and inner, which is normal but then when trying to figure out how they had the wrapper centered by viewing the code normally through ctrl+u, I noticed that there is a line of code that exists in inspect element that isn't there when I view the code elsewhere. First of all, that code is this:

```
 <div class="bgView" style="display: block; position: fixed; top: 0px;"></div>
```

So, could anyone tell me the reason for this?

The website:
http://www.tekken-official.jp/tk7ac/

Check line 79 for missing code.

Comment: Interesting. This div changes its position from static (default) to absolute and then to fixed as you scroll down. It's meant to show the background that is being scrolled to some point and from some level, doesn't scroll any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This div is here to show this image http://www.tekken-official.jp/tk7ac/images/common/bg_main_09.jpg in background.

To find out, just reveal the div in the devtools and check out the styles panel.

Answer (score 0):

The Elements panel in Dev Tools shows the generated DOM - the source shows the source as it is in the .html file. That line was generated via Javascript, as seen in line 39 here: http://www.tekken-official.jp/tk7ac/js/common.js